# java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError is happened when i use validation in spring mvc

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

When I'm using validation I get [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iXoY.png). It finds the errors but when I return to the same jsp page again it throws these exception, otherwise it works. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Formatting of image anchor

Comment: Error happens with neatbeans. I am not sure   i think that it was a bug. It worked with sts and intellij idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you may have defined `groups` and `payload` as `@NotNull` annotation in your entity.

And your form submission is not submitting any value for that so it is going `null` and because of that your are getting these errors.

Better to define BindingResult and control on errors like below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String create(@Valid EntityPojo entity, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return getPath() + "/update"; //here you return the same page with errors
    }
    //here you proceed further if there is no error
}
```